# When the application is restarted, dynamically generated Buttons are not present?

Tags: android, button, dynamically-generated

I'm using a predefined Button to add new Buttons dynamically.
But when I restart the application, the dynamically generated Buttons are not present in layout in which they are created.

Code to generate the Buttons.

```
if(v == btnaddnew)                          //Button to new buttons in layout Dynamically
{
    final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
    btn1.setText("New");
    btn1.setId(btncount);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
    ll.addView(btn1, lp);
    btncount++;
}
```

In main activity

```
int btncount = 15;
```

Comment: Where in your app are you running that code? What is `ll` at the time of execution`?

Comment: @FD_ that's my layout in which I'm generating buttons

Comment: Restarting the app as in closing the app or pressing the home button to let the app remain in the background ?

In case of restarting the app, it will call onCreate again and if your dynamic button creation is not in the onCreate it will not be there !

Comment: @Aadi Droid yes after closing the app and starting it again. the dynamically generated buttons are not present

Comment: Post some more code relevant to this. Its not enough to identify the issue

Comment: @Arju that's my complete code regarding generating buttons

Comment: In which method does its executed ? Does the code execute on app restart ? do this in oncreate

Comment: @Arju no i've created onClick method on button from there it is executed. When clicked on it.

Comment: Dynamically generated buttons wont remain there if you restart app unless you execute the above code again .. thats totaly wrong

Comment: @Arju so what code do i need to use to save dynamically generated buttons

Comment: You should save a flag in database or shared preference , once you generate the buttons. Then on app launch you shoul recreate them using the same code by checking the flag

Comment: @Arju can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you close your application and restart it the onCreate method is invoked for your Activity! I suspect you are loading your base layout.xml file, your dynamically added  buttons are not part of this layout and are only defined in your code. I am assuming the code to add these dynamic buttons are not in the onCreate, they are probably some button click callback?
My point is this, the dynamically added artifacts will not be present if you close the application for the reason mentioned above!

If you want to resume to the last state after closing it, you need to figure a way to store your current layout before the onDestroy method is invoked for the activity! This stored layout can be reloaded in your onCreate. Let me clear that, in your onCreate you can check if there is a stored layout if yes load from it! Else load from your layout file.

EDIT:

Look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: yes this is the problem I'm facing. So can you tell me how to store these dynamically generated buttons and to reload `Buttons` on layout after `restarting application` . So that `Dynamically Generated Buttons` will be present in `Layout` in which they were created.